# Can you say the answer five times, fast?

Tags: riddle, humor

What do you call a well-made clay jar with a face wearing glasses?

Comment: Welcome to puzzling Bafs!

Comment: Sorry your question got closed, Bafs. I don't know for sure, but I'd guess people voted to close it because it's hard to tell whether an answer is correct. You can see more details in the linked discussion on meta. In case you're not familiar with how the site works, you're welcome to edit your question and then ask for it to be reopened. It'll go into a review queue where users can vote again. Or you can start a new post for a different question. Don't be discouraged because your first try wasn't a good fit for the site.

Answer (score 20):

The answer is a:

> Respectable (well made) bespectacled (wearing glasses) receptacle (jar) spectacle (face)

Although there might be another word I've missed to make it to five

Comment: Or it could be rot13(fbzr gbc-dhnyvgl Uneel Cbggre greenpbggn cbggrel)!

Comment: I just had respectable bespectacled receptacle, but I like the last one you added.

Comment: why clay, though?

Comment: wizzwizz4, I think you meant @Bafs, not bobble ^

Comment: njzk2 - I included "clay" just to make a realistic visual. It wasn't meant to indicate part of the answer, but the commenters are using it effectively, nevertheless.

Answer (score 12):

I'd call it a

> hypnotic myopic anthropic canopic

Comment: I get the other three words, not sure where the first one comes from (beginning with 'h' in case of edit).

Comment: It's from 'well-made'. A bit of a stretch, I know.

Answer (score 6):

You could call it a:

> Cockeyed crack crock clock

> A crock may be a type of clay vessel, crack denotes its high quality, the fact that it's a clock means it has a face, and it wears glasses because it is cockeyed.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't feel like a full answer, but maybe it will trigger other ideas.

> A four A's four eyes amphora

My thinking is:

> Saying it five times fast makes me think that the answer contains repetitive sounds. Could a clay jar be an amphora? People who wear glasses can be called "four eyes". Triple A can refer to high quality, so maybe "four A's" is even better?